# LinkedList, First and Last

Tags: .net, .net-2.0, linked-list

I have a question about `LinkedList<>`.
There are properties of this list `First` and `Last`.

Will that properties correct if I will set `Last.AddNext(First)`?

I need to have a list where `Last>Next = First`, but identify clearly the `First` and `Last` elements.

I have a cycle `process.NextStep, NextStep`, but need to be able to identify each Step (`process[i]` - the *i*-th Step)

.NET 2

Comment: You mean you're trying to build a circular list? I doubt you can do that with the default class. I would expect `Last.AddNext(First)` to append a copy of the first element to the end of the list but not create a loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LinkedList<T>` doesn't support circular lists. From [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7.aspx):

> The `LinkedList<T>` class does not support chaining, splitting, cycles, or other features that can leave the list in an inconsistent state.

There's no such method as `LinkedListNode<T>.AddNext()`, but I'd expect any attempt to cause a cycle to fail with an exception.

You could always build an iterator *based* on a `LinkedList<T>` though...

(Note that this will fail if the list is empty...)

```
public static IEnumerable<Tuple<T, bool, bool>> IterateInCycles<T>
    (LinkedList<T> source)
{
    LinkedList<T> node = source.First;
    while (true)
    {
        yield return Tuple.Create(node.Value,
                                  node.Previous == null,
                                  node.Next == null);
        node = node.Next ?? source.First;
    }
}
```

Each tuple in the return sequence will be `(value, isFirst, isLast)` if you see what I mean.

Comment: e... what should this mean, or... can I replace it by something... I think this is a common problem and there should be a common solution...

Comment: what is Tuple, is it a .NET 2, or a custom class?

Comment: @serhio: It's a class in .NET 4, but you could write your own class to represent these if you want.